# What is the difference between these two OpenvSwitch commands?

Tags: sdn, openvswitch

What is the difference between these two OpenvSwitch commands? 
ovs-vsctl add-br br0 -- set bridge br0 datapath_type=netdev & ovs-vsctl add-br br0 .

Answer (score 0):

The first command sets the bridge to userspace-only mode. The second command does the default setup for the bridge.

More information can be found [here](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/openvswitch/INSTALL.userspace.md).